# create a bar like the dock bar in SWF flash format by adobe flash cc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to create a Mac-OS style of dock bar (see image below) in SWF format by using Adobe Flash CC.

[image]

Comment: why the javascript tag ? Also, what is your question ?

Comment: Because Adobe Flash CC programming language

Comment: @AL-Shehab, the programming language for Flash is called Actionscript. **(1)** Have  you ever typed Javascript and it compiled as a working SWF file? **(2)** You've told us your mission so good luck. Later if you're stuck just [**ask a Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where you explain what is problem, how you already tried to fix, etc... **(3)** Give us useful information about your problem. Put enough details to help you.

Answer (score 1):

ITS  been a while me used actionscript but i think you should make a Scroll add all elements to the scroll. See [ScrollControl](http://www.as3gamegears.com/ui/air-mobile-scrollcontroller/)

And if you have all icons in a array you can always change the scaling of one element in front and one back and of the element. Detecting [MouseEvents](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#ROLL_OVER) you can check if the mouse is over it or no.

```
 //FOR FINDING SCREENSIZE
var _stage:Stage=this.stage;
function displaySettings(): void {
        _stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        _stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        _width = _stage.stageWidth;
        _height = _stage.stageHeight;

        if (_height < _width) {
            var num: Number = _height;
            _height = _width;
            _width = num;
        }


    }
    //for scaling the object according to height
    public function scalingheight(clip: Object, percent: Number) {
        var ratio = clip.width / clip.height;
        clip.height = percent * _height;
        clip.width = clip.height * ratio;
    }

    //Scale according to width
    public function scalingwidth(clip: Object, percent: Number) {
        var ratio = clip.height / clip.width;
        clip.width = percent * _width;
        clip.height = clip.width * ratio;
    }
```

Please do a bit more research before asking a question it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you and apologize for the wrong question, my friends